# Unique children in has_many validation in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the Google places API to collect any number of locations on a profile. Each location has the profile_id, 4 address fields and a lat and long. I want to make sure that all locations for each profile are unique.

At the moment I'm using the code below to validate the uniqueness of the 4 address fields which is working perfectly however this results in a validation error being returned to the view. I would rather save the profile and locations (with duplicates removed) without returning an error to the user.

What is the best way of going about this? Is there a rails approach or should I create my own before-validation function?

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, allow_destroy: true

        etc etc

end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :profile

    # Only allow unique locations for each profile
    validates_uniqueness_of :profile_id, scope: [:sublocality, :locality, :administrative_area_level_1, :country]

        etc etc

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `error[:profile_id].present?` in `after_validation` callback.
If error related to `profile_id` is present - remove duplicates and `save` again

You should be careful if you have other validations related to `profile_id` and check for presence of specific error message in that case.